# How many words with $N$-characters can be formed from the numbers $\{0, 1, 2\}$, such that adjacent numbers have maximum difference 1?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations, inclusion-exclusion, dynamic-programming

> How many words with $N$-characters can be formed from the numbers
>   $\{0, 1, 2\}$, such that adjacent numbers have maximum difference $1$?
>   Example: For $N = 2$ there are $7$ words that can be formed: $<0,0>;<0,1>;<1,0>; <1,1>; <1,2>; <2,1>; <2,2>$. The $<>$ notation specifies a
>   single word. If $N = 10$, how many words can be formed?
>   a. 8119
>   b. 8121
>   c. 8123
>   d. 8125
>   e. 8127

I have tried to answer this problem by counting all possible words, then subtracting those words that violate the rules, but I found the answer isn't one of the choices.

$<a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j>$

All combination is $3^{10} = 59049$
when the difference is more than $1$ then the only possibility is that the word contains a $0$ and a $2$ that are adjacent to each other.

Please help me THANK YOU!

Comment: Oh I knew! this is a dynamic programming question, isn't it?

Comment: @the4seasons The linked question is similar but not a duplicate!

Comment: Ahh I saw that the solutions were similar... sorry, and thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Let $a_N$, $b_N$ and $c_N$ be the number of $N$-character strings that can be formed from $\{0,1,2\}$, such that adjacent numbers have the maximum difference $1$ and it ends with $0$, $1$, and $2$ respectively.
Moreover let $s_N=a_N+b_N+c_N$ be the total number of such $N$-character strings. Then, for $N\geq 1$, they satisfy the recurrences
$$\begin{cases}
a_{N+1}=a_N+b_N &\text{(before the ending $0$ there is $0$ or $1$)}\\
b_{N+1}=a_N+b_N+c_N=s_N &\text{(before the ending $1$ there is $0$, $1$ or $2$)}\\
c_{N+1}=b_N+c_N &\text{(before the ending $2$ there is $1$ or $2$)}
\end{cases}$$
Hence, by taking the sum of these three recurrences, we find
$$s_{N+1}=2s_N+b_N=2s_N+s_{N-1}.$$
Now $s_1=3$ and $s_2=7$ (see your remark).
Can you take it from here and find $s_{10}$?

Comment: Thank you so much!! I love this solution. Actually I have found the right solution by myself, but this solution is much simpler and much clearer than mine :D

Comment: I still confused. Why b[N] is equal to s[N-1]?

Comment: Because $b_{N+1}=a_N+b_N+c_N$ and $s_N=a_N+b_N+c_N$.

Comment: Ok I understand now. Thanks